# Loading site configuration from ini file

Tags: coldfusion, configuration, cfml

I load in static setting via an ini file. Ini file have the benefits

- of NOT being server by most web servers by default.
- easier to edit than XML
- even simplier than JSON

Setting get loaded in Application.cfc

```
void function setupApplication() output="false" {
... 
application.stAdminSetting  = application.loadini("admin\standard.ini");
...
}
```

Application.cfc has this as a function...

```
<cffunction name="loadini" output="false" returnType="struct">
<cfargument name="configfile" required="true" type="string" hint="reads from currentTemplate">


<cfscript>
var stResult = {};

var iniFilePath = "#GetDirectoryFromPath(GetBaseTemplatePath())##arguments.configfile#";
var stSection = getProfileSections(iniFilePath);


for(var section in stSection)   {

    var CurrentSection = evaluate("stSection.#section#");   

    var stData = {};

    for(var i = 1; i <= ListLen(CurrentSection); i++)   {
        var key = ListGetAt(CurrentSection, i);

        stData[key] = getProfileString(iniFilePath, section, key);

        }

    setvariable("stResult.#section#", stData);
    }


return stResult;    
</cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

The ini file can have any number of setting. In particular my ini file has:

```
[ws]
comment=http://xxxxx.com/resource/comment.cfc?wsdl
ior=http://xxxxx.com/resource/ior.cfc?wsdl
node=http://xxxxx.com/resource/node.cfc?wsdl
pref=http://xxxxx.com/resource/pref.cfc?wsdl
traffic=http://xxxxx.com/resource/traffic.cfc?wsdl
```

What kinds of things can I do to improve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `evaluate()` here:

```
var CurrentSection = evaluate("stSection.#section#");
```

Simply do this:

```
var CurrentSection = stSection[section]);
```

Similarly you don't need to use `setVariable()`:

```
setvariable("stResult.#section#", stData);
```

Simply:

```
stResult[section] = stData;
```

Answer (score 4):

What kind of things are you looking to improve? Your solution looks pretty straightforward. The only problem with an ini file is that ColdFusion can't instantly/natively parse it. Whereas XML/JSON can be parsed directly into a Coldfusion Struct.

```
<cfscript>
public struct function loadini( required string configFile) {
    var stResult = {};
    var iniFilePath = "#GetDirectoryFromPath(GetBaseTemplatePath())##arguments.configfile#";
    var stSection = getProfileSections(iniFilePath);

    // loop over the sections
     for (section in stSection) {
        // loop over the list of variables in the ini file
        for (var i=0;i<=listLen(stSection[section]);i++) {
            // result.section.variable = value 
            stResult[section][listGetAt(stSection[section],i)] = GetProfileString(iniFilePath, section, listGetAt(stSection[section],i) ) ;
        }
     }
    return stResult;        
}
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#loadini('test.ini')#">
```